# Building a custom threejs geometry

Tags: javascript, three.js, geometry

I need to generate a Threejs geometry which is more or less a cube, but with a dent on the top plane formed by a quadratic curve.
Like this, but upside down and dent extending over the entire plane:

https://www.iconfinder.com/icons/3144889/cube_dent_elastic_erosion_pack_push_soft_icon

How do I build this geometry?

Thank you

Comment: Do you want to do it in 3d editing software, or code?

Answer (score 0):

In blender, you could subdivide a cube and then use proportional vertex editing to pull that middle vertex in and you can get that profile. Then optionally set smooth shading and add an edge split modifier.. export as .glb.

Answer (score 0):

`THREE.BoxGeometry();` The box geometry object might not suit your since it only takes in 8 vertices as arguments.

If you want to add a custom shape, you can refer to [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/ShapeGeometry), and the buttom curve cylinder extrude can be made with `var geometry = new THREE.CylinderGeometry()` at [here](https://threejs.org/docs/#api/en/geometries/CylinderGeometry)